# Find expression for p-value of significance test in terms of Φ(f(a)) when the value of a is unknown?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

What keeps me from solving this question is that the values that a can take are not given, hence we don't know where in the distribution of X it'll be located. It if were, let's say on the left side of µ, then I'd find P(X<a) and times that by two but since I don't know where it's located it might as well be on the right side and then P(X<a) would not give half of alpha...

The answer to this question is 2phi(-(15-a)/1.5)
[image]

Comment: is it so difficult to begin to use MathJax for your formulas?

Comment: Yeh, sorry, it's just, I don't know where to find it in the posting section...

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is not needed. They ask you to find the p-value, that is the area of the two tails of the gaussian

I suppose you know that $a\sim N(\mu;\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ and thus your p-value is

$$\mathbb{P}[Z >\frac{|a-15|}{\sqrt{\frac{4.5^2}{9}}}]=\mathbb{P}\Bigg[Z >\frac{|a-15|}{1.5}\Bigg]$$

..and this is exaclty what  you solution states (it is just a matter of writing this probability in terms of $\Phi$ but I think you can do it by yourself)

After calculating it, if you  p-value is lower than the fixed $\alpha$ you will reject your null hypothesis, if it will be higher you will not reject it.

Comment: Right, okay, I now understand that α is not needed. However, how did you know to standardize the value of a? Wouldn't 2Φ(|a|) be equally correct?

Comment: @Manolis Gustavsson: no, under $H_0$ the sample mean is gaussian distribuited with mean 15 and variance $\frac{4.5^2}{9}$

Comment: thank you for your explanation. However, in your calculations above, shouldn’t we be using the inequality ’smaller or equal to’ instead so that we can use Φ(z), and then wouldn’t we have -abs(a-15)/1.5? (I’m just asking cause I’m not sure myself)

Comment: @Manolis Gustavsson : do a drawing and use the symmetry of $\Phi$

Comment: Okay, one last thing, how do I go from 2Φ(-abs(a-15)/1.5) to 2Φ(-((15-a)/1.5))?